# send japanese character through XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

I have to send the japanese name trough XMLHttpRequest. but it displays encoding problem... my tpl page is in utf-8 charset.

here is my code.

```
function getFormData(dno,rno) {
    var name = document.getElementById("f_nickname").value;
    var digNo = dno;
    var resNo = rno;
    var strVal = digNo + "-" + resNo;
    stp.push(strVal);

         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         if (!xhr) return false;
         var url = 'ajax.php' + '?prc=' + 'diagnoses' + '&name=' + name + '&diagres=' + stp;
         xhr.open('POST', url, true);
         xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         xhr.send(stp);
        return true;
```

}

i have passing url like this:

```
http://crp.com/ajax.php?prc=diagnoses&name=大阪&diagres=0-0,1-3,2-2,3-3,4-3,5-2
```

but it displays in Ajax.php like

```
http://crp.com/ajax.php?prc=diagnoses&name=ƒsƒU&diagres=0-0,1-3,2-2,3-3,4-3,5-2
```

tried in many ways... How to solve? 
thanks in advance...

Comment: have you tried setting `xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Charset", "unicode-1-1;q=0.8");`http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: I wouldn't have expected it to make a difference here, but you should run your strings through `encodeURIComponent` before putting them into the URI.

Comment: "but it displays in Ajax.php like" — How are you testing that?

Comment: Why are you passing an array to `send()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent` for such parameters in url.

```
var url = 'ajax.php' + '?prc=' + 'diagnoses' + '&name=' + encodeURIComponent(name) + '&diagres=' + stp;
```

It will result in url like:

```
http://crp.com/ajax.php?prc=diagnoses&name=%E5%A4%A7%E9%98%AA&diagres=0-0,1-3,2-2,3-3,4-3,5-2
```

And webserver will handle it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/xml;charset=utf-8');
```

Use:

`encodeURIComponent(name)` instead of just `name`

Comment: `stp` is not an XML document. Why would that help? The problem is in the URL anyway.